# Insert login/registration icon

Tags: php, html, wordpress

There is a WordPress site with a Twenty-Twenty theme.

[image]

1. I removed the Example Page link in the header and inserted a search form instead and as well as two inscriptions - Login | Registration and drawing entryicon.svg.

```html
<div class="header-navigation-wrapper">
                        <?php get_search_form( $echo = true ); ?>
                        
                            <div class="kCNgDb">
                            <span class="eEkWAa"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?> /entryicon.svg"></img></span>
                            <span class="gxtXIp">Login</span>
                            <span class="bidiEP">|</span>
                            <span class="jCpPzc">Registration</span>
                            </div>
```

2. I get an error when reloading the page

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'get_stylesheet_directory_uri' (T_STRING) in C:\OSPanel\domains\digitalelectronics.ru\wp-content\themes\twentwenty-child\header.php on line 86`

[image]

And the drawing is not displayed:

[image]

Comment: `<?phpecho` <- missing space?

Comment: ...and there is an unnecessary space between `?>` and `/entryicon.svg`